# Open popup in IE by window.open

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to automate the filling of a form. The form is in an intranet.

During the routine, the main IE page opens a popup launched by a javascript function in an anchor tag of HTML code. This function uses "window.open".

How do I control this popup? It doesn't appear in Shell.application.

I read an InternetExplorer object Events Method can intercept the popup opened with window.open: IE_NexWindow3

How can I use this event method in Excel VBA code?

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)

Function GetobIEOBject(URL As String) As Object
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    For Each obj In objShell.Windows
        If TypeName(obj.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If obj.LocationURL = URL Then Set GetobIEOBject = obj
        End If
    Next obj
End Function

Sub WaitIE(objIE As InternetExplorer)
    'On boucle tant que la page n'est pas totalement chargée
    Do While objIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub

Sub Essai()

Dim IE1 As InternetExplorer
Dim IE2 As InternetExplorer

Dim IE1Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim IE2Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim Frame1_Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim htmltable As htmltable
Dim Generic As HTMLGenericElement
Dim B_Aff_Banque_Horraire As HTMLGenericElement

Dim URL As String
Dim URL2 As String
Dim tag As String
Dim CP As String
Dim index As Integer

' Affectation des variables adresse site internet"

URL = "http://fakepath"
URL2 = "/Tap/Gerer/TapGrHoraire.jsp"

' affectation du site sur URL à la l'objet EI2

Set IE1 = GetobIEOBject(URL)
Set IE1Doc = IE1.document
IE1.Visible = True

'dans le document HTML (de IE1) un nouveau dcument est attaché a une balise frame
'Affectation variable pour document balise frame 1

Set Frame1_Doc = IE1Doc.frames("contenu").document.frames.Item(1).document

' recherche du formulaire HTML

For index = 0 To 200
    Set Generic = Frame1_Doc.getElementsByTagName("form")(index)
    On Error GoTo saut1
    If Generic.Name = "Formulaire" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

' Recherche de la table générale identifié par la class "nn"

For index = 0 To 200
    Set htmltable = Generic.getElementsByTagName("table")(index)
    On Error GoTo saut1
    If htmltable.ClassName = "nn" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

' Recherche de la table contenu - pas de name, id, ou class etc...

Set htmltable = htmltable.Children(0).Children(1).Children(0).Children(1)

' Rechercher Afficher banque horraire pas de name, id, ou class etc...

Set B_Aff_Banque_Horraire = htmltable.Children(1).Children(0).Children(0).Children(0)
B_Aff_Banque_Horraire.Click

Set IE1 = GetobIEOBject(URL)
Set IE1Doc = IE1.document
IE1.Visible = True


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'Routine de remplassage a réaliser
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

'boucle pour trouver la case du tabeleau de la du mois et entree le code horraire
' il gau = "AJ_" & Jou_du_mois & "_AG_" & CP & "_"

Msgbox "fin"

Set IE1 = Nothing
Set IE2 = Nothing
Set IE1Doc = Nothing
Set IE2Doc = Nothing
Set Frame1_Doc = Nothing
Set htmltable = Nothing
Set Generic = Nothing
Set B_Aff_Banque_Horraire = Nothing

End Sub
```

HTML CODE anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:afficherBanqueHoraire();" onclick="nePasAvertirEnQuittant=true;" onmouseover="return overlib('Pour afficher la banque horaire', CAPTION, 'Cliquez ici ...');" onmouseout="return nd();" class="orangegras">Afficher la
                                            banque horaire</a>
```

HTML

```
Function javascript:afficherBanqueHoraire() :
```

javascript

```js
    function afficherBanqueHoraire() {
            try {
              if (oBanqueHoraire == null || oBanqueHoraire.closed) {
                  if (document.all){
                      //Cas ie
                      oBanqueHoraire = showModelessDialog("TapGrHoraire.jsp",window,"status:no;dialogLeft:200;dialogTop:100;dialogWidth:900px;dialogHeight:300px;resizable:yes;help:no");
                  } else {
                      oBanqueHoraire = window.open("/Tap/Gerer/TapGrHoraire.jsp","WinTapGrHoraire","status=no, Left=200, Top=100, Width=900px, Height=200px, resizable=yes, help=no"); 
                  }  
              }
          oBanqueHoraire.focus();
          } catch(ex) {
              alert("L\'accès à la banque horaire est impossible !");
          }
     }
```

Comment: Can you please inform us, what do you want to do with this popup? Do you want to close it or do some other processing on it? Can you please show a picture of this popup? It can really help us to understand the issue properly. When you try to loop through IE windows using shell then try to match the title of that popup may help you to find it. Also please inform us the purpose of clicking this link from your automation code.

Comment: Since this is IE the javascript test for `doument.all` will pass, so it will use `showModelessDialog` and not `window.open`.  You could try just opening the new window directly - you already know the URL it will use.

Comment: Thanks TIm, i'm not comfortable with javascript then... You must be right.

Comment: I Tried to open it in a new pages , but it doesn't work. I can  make selection but when a want to use it to fill form , it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry Deepak, i 'am new and i am not allowed to paste picture in the question tag!!! In the popup there is a table with a dozen of cells. it's a sort of Tool used to select values .. Then you can fill the form with this values  in the main page.

Comment: You said you can open it in a new page and make the selection but not able to fill the form. Can you please show your approach? We can try to check whether there is any way to make it work. As an alternative, if possible for you then you can try to make a test with the Selenium IE web driver. It may help you to switch to that dialog.